# Echo some command lines in a shell script (echo on for single command)

Tags: bash, shell, echo

In shell scripts I would like to echo some of the major (long running) commands for status and debug reason. I know I can enable an echo for all commands with `set -x` or `set -v`. But I don't want to see all the commands (specially not the echo commands). Is there a way to turn on the echo for just one command?

I could do like this, but that's ugly and echoes the line `set +x` as well:

```
#!/bin/sh

dir=/tmp
echo List $dir

set -x
ls $dir
set +x

echo Done!
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why not just add some echos at various key point in the script?

Comment: @John3136: Because it is fiddly and unreliable...in particular, you end up duplicating the command, writing it out twice, which becomes a maintenance liability.

Comment: That was my first idea, but the commands I actually run are several lines long - it will be a bigger mess...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12231792/11543 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2853803/11543

Comment: Another reason not to do that is because it willl with quotes and variable expansion and then you still don't know the exact command you're running.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

At the cost of a process per occasion, you can use:

```
(set -x; ls $dir)
```

This runs the command in a sub-shell, so the `set -x` only affects what's inside the parentheses.  You don't need to code or see the `set +x`.  I use this when I need to do selective tracing.

Comment: The only time this technique causes trouble is if the commands to be traced need to set variables for use in the parent shell.  Basically, the sub-shell can't modify the original shell's variables, so the modifications are strictly local to the code inside the parentheses.

Comment: Also, `{ set +x; } 2>/dev/null` - via [Bash set +x without it being printed - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19226038/277826)

Comment: @sdaau: interesting — obvious once seen, but not until you've seen it.

Answer (score 5):

How about using this function?

```
runtraced() {
    echo "$@"
    "$@"
}

dosomething
runtraced dosomethingelse
```

Comment: That is quite neat — until you need to trace a pipeline.  `runtraced ls | wc -l` doesn't do what you expect (it traces the `ls` but not the `wc -l`).  Or other similar constructs.

Comment: True. Perhaps one working version would include an `eval "$1"` instead (use `runtraced "ls | wc -l"`).

Answer (score 3):

Based on Jonathan Leffler answer, this works the same way, just a little more clear because there is noting needed after the command. But you need to specify which shell should be used. This is a example for sh:

```
sh -xc ls $dir
```

Comment: your version could need extra quoting and escaping with pipelines. For example (set -x; echo 'toronto"s rules' | wc -c) versus sh -xc  'echo '"'"'toronto"s rules'"'"' | wc -c'

Comment: True, it doesn't work in all situations so well. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do this is with a `heredoc` and an uninterpreted string. It is POSIX portable and fast:

```
...
% cmd='ls ${dir}'
% sh -x <<_EOF_
> ${cmd}
> _EOF_
...
```

You can build out entire scripts in this way, parsing and/or modifying them programmatically as needed, saving them to and calling them from shell variables, and running them all from within another script or shell function:

```
...
% script="$(cat </some/entire/script.sh)"
% script="$(pipeline | processing | on | ${script})"    
% sh -x <<_EOF_ 2>&1 | grep ${specific_cmds_Im_looking_for}
> ${script}
> _EOF_
<desired output>
```

In my answer to [POSIX compliant way to see if a function is defined in an sh script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447555/posix-compliant-way-to-see-if-a-function-is-defined-in-an-sh-script/19885768#19885768) I describe the hows and whys of this in greater detail. And at Stack Exchange I discuss pretty thoroughly how the `heredoc` can be used to solve some annoying quoting problems in answer to [Is there a way to get *actual* (uninterpreted) shell arguments in a function or script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102310/52934).

-Mike