# how to silently disable xtrace in a shell script?

Tags: shell

I'm writing a shell script that loops over some values and run a long command line for each value. I'd like to print out these commands along the way, just like `make` does when running a makefile. I know I could just "echo" all commands before running them, but it feels inelegant. So I'm looking at `set -x` and similar mechanisms instead :

```
#!/bin/sh

for value in a long list of values
do
    set -v
    touch $value # imagine a complicated invocation here
    set +v
done
```

My problem is: at each iteration, not only is the interresting line printed out, but also the `set +x` line as well. Is it somehow possible to prevent that ? If not, what workaround do you recommend ?

PS: the MWE above uses `sh`, but I also have `bash` and `zsh` installed in case that helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash set +x without it being printed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195655/bash-set-x-without-it-being-printed)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sandbox it in a subshell:

```
(set -x; do_thing_you_want_traced)
```

Of course, changes to variables or the environment made in that subshell will be lost.

If you REALLY care about this, you could also use a DEBUG trap (using `set -T` to cause it to be inherited by functions) to implement your own `set -x` equivalent.

For instance, if using bash:

```
trap_fn() {
  [[ $DEBUG && $BASH_COMMAND != "unset DEBUG" ]] && \
    printf "[%s:%s] %s\n" "$BASH_SOURCE" "$LINENO" "$BASH_COMMAND"
  return 0 # do not block execution in extdebug mode
}
trap trap_fn DEBUG

DEBUG=1
# ...do something you want traced...
unset DEBUG
```

That said, emitting BASH_COMMAND (as a DEBUG trap can do) is not fully equivalent of `set -x`; for instance, it does not show post-expansion values.

Answer (score 7):

You want to try using a single-line xtrace:

```
function xtrace() {
  # Print the line as if xtrace was turned on, using perl to filter out
  # the extra colon character and the following "set +x" line.
  (
    set -x
    # Colon is a no-op in bash, so nothing will execute.
    : "$@"
    set +x
  ) 2>&1 | perl -ne 's/^[+] :/+/ and print' 1>&2
  # Execute the original line unmolested
  "$@"
}
```

The original command executes in the same shell under an identity transformation. Just prior to running, you get a non-recursive xtrace of the arguments. This allows you to xtrace the commands you care about without spamming stederr with duplicate copies of every "echo" command.

```
# Example
for value in $long_list; do
  computed_value=$(echo "$value" | sed 's/.../...')
  xtrace some_command -x -y -z $value $computed_value ...
done
```

Comment: I LOVE this for reasons other than what caused me to google this question! Thank you for not sticking to OP question Description. (It really annoys me when people complain about answers that loosely apply to OP Topic. It's about the 1,000,000s who will come after the 1 OP.)

Comment: Thanks, although I'd say that I am answering the OP, it's just that I'm answering the unasked question of how to accomplish what they were trying to accomplish with their "set -x" and "set +x" pairs, rather than being constrained by the literal question that they asked. I've found that to be a useful tactic in many professional settings. People tend to ask for something hyper-specific that's merely an example of what a solution to their problem might look like.

Answer (score 1):

Next command disables 'xtrace' option:

$ set +o xtrace

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer that over `set +x`?

Comment: To be clear, the reason this isn't responsive is that the OP asked for "silently". This isn't silent; `set +o xtrace`  is included in the trace log, just as `set +x` is in the trace log in the OP's original code (which is what they asked the question to know how to solve).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be to do with when the redirection to stderr takes effect.

To get the effect you require, simply run the *set* in a list:

```
echo $-
{ set +x; } 2> /dev/null
echo $-
```

giving you

```
himxBHs
himBHs
```

Quite a bit cheaper than a subshell.

Comment: should be `2>/dev/null`, no?

Comment: Yes thank you @SpinUp __ A Davis. Not a deliberate mistake, just deliberate idiocy :)

Answer (score 0):

I thought of

```
 set -x >/dev/null 2>&1; echo 1; echo 2; set +x >/dev/null 2>&1
```

but got

```
+ echo 1
1
+ echo 2
2
+ 1> /dev/null 2>& 1
```

I'm surprised by these results. .... But

```
set -x ; echo 1; echo 2; set +x
+ echo 1
1
+ echo 2
2
```

looks to meet your requirement.

I saw similar results when I put each statement on its only line (excepting the set +x)

IHTH.

Comment: FYI -- `set -x` output goes to stderr only, unless overridden with BASH_XTRACEFD in bash 4.

Comment: ...by the way, mileage does _indeed_ vary; I can't reproduce the behavior reported here on bash 4.2.45(1).

Comment: @charlesDuffy: I use ksh, but I read about bash (here) all the time. Thanks for the details! Good luck to all.