# Suppress `set -v` / `set -x` logging only for a single line in bash

Tags: bash, echo

I'm writing a .sh script like the following:

```
echo script started
./some_command > output_file
echo script ended
```

I'd like the output to be the following:

```
script started   
./some_command > output_file   
script ended
```

I've tried `set -v`, `set +v` but it didn't work properly,
is there anything similar to `@echo` in batch?

Thanks

Comment: at the beginning of your shell script use `#!/bin/sh -x` This will output each execution

Comment: I was going to suggest you use standard error like so: `echo script started >&2`, then run your script with `myscript 2> /dev/null`, but that does not seem to be what you want.

Comment: yes, I want to output my commands except the echo command, sorry for the confusion

Comment: What you are trying to do seems non standard and issues prone.

Comment: @user1464870 Don't give up so fast and accept an answer you don't like... You just posted this 3 hours ago. Maybe change the title because what you really want to do seems to be print the commands within a bash script, except don't echo the echo command twice...

Comment: If you're running with `set -x`, does `: script started` do what you want? It prints that line to stderr (or wherever you have `BASH_XTRACEFD` directed), and doesn't generate an additional line with output.

Comment: btw, [`set -x` without it being printed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195655/bash-set-x-without-it-being-printed) is very closely related, perhaps even duplicate.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This does what you'd like :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "script started"
echo "./some_command > output_file"
./some_command > output_file
echo "script ended"
```

Comment: I have thought about that, but what if I have hundreds of lines. that creates a maintenance problem

Comment: This is the straightforward way.

Comment: @rid, there's a way with `eval` but don't use it (security issues). [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).  'eval' is a common misspelling of 'evil'. If eval is the answer, surely you are asking the wrong question. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Comment: @sputnick, seems like there's no better solutions. I guess I'll take yours as the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Using `bash -x` from the comment by @TopGunCoder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -x
echo $0 started  > /dev/null
ls
pwd
./some_command > output_file
date
echo $0 ended  > /dev/null
```

The OUTPUT is each command followed by its result:

```
+ echo /Users/myuser/scripts/tbash.sh started
+ ls
[...my directory listing...]
+ pwd
/Users/myuser
+ ./some_command
[the output of "some command"]
+ date
Wed Sep 25 17:06:25 PDT 2013
+ echo /Users/myuser/scripts/tbash.sh ended
```

Comment: The command doesn't even need to be `echo`, then -- one could run `: "$0" started`, and have the same effect, but with a shorter prefix and no need for a `>/dev/null` redirection. (`:` is a synonym for `true`, but one conventionally/traditionally understood to indicate this kind of placeholder use).

Comment: Thanks, Charles. I didn't know about `:`. This was answered a long time ago, and I think I just adapted the OP's example. Not sure why I even put the redirection.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to `bash -x` the whole file, then as long as you don't mind running in a subshell, you can simply do this per line:

`(set -x; command ...)`

Quick and easy to use. I also use this in my git config to echo git aliased commands so I remember what they're aliased to

```
~/.gitconfig
[alias]
    c    = "!f() { (set -x; git commit --verbose \"$@\"; ) }; f"
    c-   = "!f() { (set -x; git commit -m \"$@\"; ) }; f"
    dt   = "!f() { (set -x; git describe --long --tags;) }; f;"
    push = "!f() { (set -x; git push origin \"$@\";) }; f"
    s    = "!f() { (set -x; git status -sb \"$@\"; ) }; f"
    ...
```

```
$ git s
+ git status -sb
## main...origin/main
 M file-1
 M file-2
?? file-3
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `echo` just replace it with `#` that way echo isn't displayed and you still get some feedback