# shell script question: { set +x; } 2>/dev/null

Tags: shell

I was reading a stackoverflow page:
[Bash set +x without it being printed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195655/bash-set-x-without-it-being-printed)

My question is simple as you see:

```bash
{ set +x; } 2>/dev/null
```

On the shell script, what does the `{ set +x; }` mean?

I already have answers about the `2>/dev/null` so far.

but I cannot find any explanation about the `{set +x;}` but `set -x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set -x` enable a mode, that prints all executed commands to the terminal.

`set +x` disables this mode.

[source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)